# Dynamic color Gradient

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in making some kind of dynamic color scaling in excel.
I need to scale one column but based on the values from other column. Actually, I need to reset the color scaling to the second column whenever value on the first column changes.

Comment: Providing an example would be helpful

Comment: Why use VBA rather than conditional formatting (which supports various color gradients)?

Comment: Those are not really examples which are adequate to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here is the example

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fsRyX-BkWloHxj9-4wXKYyiS48YkKmED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, seems like you want value-specific conditional formatting.

- So all rows in column A that contain value `Value1` should have their own colour scale in column B.
- Similarly, all rows in A that contain value `Value2` should have their own colour scale in column B.
- And so forth for all remaining values in column A.

One approach to do this might involve VBA and consist of the following.

- You can get all rows where column A contains a certain value (e.g. `Value1`) with `Range.AutoFilter` in conjunction with `Range.SpecialCells`.
- You can add conditional formatting with `Range.FormatConditions.Add`.
- It makes sense to complete the above two steps only once for each unique value. Otherwise, the steps will be completed for every value in column A.
- You can get code to run when a change occurs in column A using `Worksheet_Change` event and some conditional `IF` logic.

Assuming your values in column A are sorted (as they appear to be in the document you've shared), the code might look something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ApplyValueSpecificConditionalFormatting(ByVal columnToFormat As Variant)

    Dim filterRangeIncludingHeaders As Range
    Set filterRangeIncludingHeaders = Me.Range("A1", Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, columnToFormat).End(xlUp))

    Dim filterRangeExcludingHeaders As Range
    Set filterRangeExcludingHeaders = filterRangeIncludingHeaders.Offset(1).Resize(filterRangeIncludingHeaders.Rows.Count - 1)

    filterRangeExcludingHeaders.Columns(columnToFormat).FormatConditions.Delete ' Prevent redundant/obsolete rules.

    ' In your case, values in column A appear to be sorted. So we can assume that whenever
    ' the current row's value (in column A) is not the same as the previous row's value (in column A),
    ' that we have a new, unique value -- for which we should add a new colour scale in column B.
    ' A better, more explicit way would be to build a unique "set" of values (possibly accomodating
    ' type differences e.g. "2" and 2), and loop through the set.

    Dim inputArray() As Variant
    inputArray = filterRangeIncludingHeaders.Value

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = (LBound(inputArray, 1) + 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        If inputArray(rowIndex, 1) <> inputArray(rowIndex - 1, 1) Then
            filterRangeIncludingHeaders.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=inputArray(rowIndex, 1)

            Dim cellsToFormat As Range

            On Error Resume Next
            Set cellsToFormat = filterRangeExcludingHeaders.Columns(columnToFormat).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not (cellsToFormat Is Nothing) Then
                ' Probably best to put the below in its own function.
                With cellsToFormat.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(colorscaleType:=2)
                    .SetFirstPriority
                    .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
                    .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = vbWhite
                    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
                    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = 8109667
                End With
            End If

            Set cellsToFormat = Nothing
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    Me.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        ApplyValueSpecificConditionalFormatting columnToFormat:=2 ' or B
        ApplyValueSpecificConditionalFormatting columnToFormat:="C" ' or 2
    End If
End Sub
```

The code should be placed in the code module of the worksheet (containing values in column A and colour scales in column B).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Andrija_Grozdanovic, I just noticed a small issue: `Set cellsToFormat = filterRangeExcludingHeaders.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` should be `Set cellsToFormat = filterRangeExcludingHeaders.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. Otherwise, the colour scale is being applied to column A as well (even if you can't see it). I'll edit the code to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, fixed it, thanks a lot. One more question, can you give me modification if I want to color some column C also, based on values from A ?

Comment: @Andrija_Grozdanovic, have edited my answer. It should now work the same for columns B, C (or whatever column you pass) -- as long as the data begins in cell `A1`.

Comment: thanks for your code here. I must admit that I am complete newbie in VBA so, can you explain to me how to run the code ?

Comment: @Andrija_Grozdanovic Which part are you unsure about? Open the Excel workbook, then open VB Editor (Alt+F11), then find the code module for the worksheet that needs to have value specific formatting applied to it (look in the top left of the window, near where it says `ThisWorkbook`), copy-paste the code there. Then enter a value in column 1 and see if the code runs and formatting is applied.

Comment: ok I got it, thanks a lot. Code is working now, but still it is like stuck on column C,if I change column name (in worksheet change sub) for example to column D, it still colors the C column

Comment: @Andrija_Grozdanovic I recommend manually deleting/removing all conditional formatting from the sheet, then click the `Set filterRangeIncludingHeaders = ...` line in the code and press `F9`. You should see a red circle appear at the start of that. Now go back to the sheet and make a change in column `A`, which should cause the code to run but it should also then "pause" on the line with the red circle. Now press `F8` (repeatedly) to step through the code line by line. You want to make sure that the `With cellsToFormat.FormatConditions.AddColorScale...` section is run.

Comment: If that section doesn't run, perhaps one of the `If` conditions is evaluating to `False`. You should also check the value of `columnToFormat` and/or the address of `cellsToFormat` in the locals window (`View > Locals Window`) to make sure it is as expected. Also, the code expects your data to begin in cell `A1` (including headers).